Magento 2 - Varnish - Cloudways - Hit Rate below 50%
I have a multistore Magento 2.4.6 app hosted on Cloudways.
They have a built in Varnish solution (which is convenient).
But I have noticed that my Varnish hit rate is always below 55%.
I asked the Cloudways support about this and they've said:
*"Cache HIT RATE actually depends upon multiple factors including but not limited to number of POST calls on the site, cache PURGE calls, Cache expiry and many more.
Checking the logs of application, I found the site was not showing or showing very low number of POST calls in access logs but looking at the recent logs, POST calls have increased a lot and when you make any updates on the site, a POST call is generated which clears cache as well to show latest content on the frontend"*
Is that true that every time there is a POST call on the site the cache purges?
That seems strange, because with Magento there are so many POST calls due to customer contact, checkout, SOAP, PayPal IPN, etc. etc......
So the cache would be purging pretty much constantly?
#confused

There are a variety of reasons why cache misses occur. I'll focus on the 3 main ones:

The request is for a resource that has never been requested before or because the object has expired
The request is for an uncacheable resource.
The cache is forcefully emptied, because there's not enough space. This results in cache misses.

Finding cache misses (regular & expired content)
Run the following varnishlog command to view all cache misses as they occur:
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "VCL_call eq 'MISS'"

If that's a bit too verbose and you only want to know the URL, run the following command to figure out the cache misses:
sudo varnishlog -g request -i requrl -q "VCL_call eq 'MISS'"

Run the following command to see how many objects have been expired:
sudo varnishstat -f MAIN.n_expired

Finding uncacheable objects
Objects that are not cacheable because of uncacheable request parameters or uncacheable response parameters can be found using the following command:
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "TTL[6] eq 'uncacheable' or VCL_call eq 'PASS'"

Have a look at the following tutorial to learn why they aren't cacheable: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/troubleshooting-varnish/#varnish-is-not-caching
Counting the number of cache bypasses and hit-for-misses (uncacheable) can be done using the following command:
sudo varnishstat -f MAIN.s_pass -f MAIN.cache_hitmiss

Checking whether the cache is forcefully emptied (because of lack of space)
If you suspect cache misses occur because the cache is forcefully emptied, you can check this using the following counter:
sudo varnishstat -f MAIN.n_lru_nuked

If the counter increases, it means content has to be "nuked" out of the cache because of lack of space.
Sidenote: how to track cache purges
If you believe your Magento setup is constantly purging objects, you can use varnishlog to keep track of this.
Simply run the following command:
sudo varnishlog -g request -q "ReqMethod eq 'PURGE'"

Sidenote 2: tracking top misses, bypasses, purges
varnishlog gives you the ability to inspect the logs for certain patterns. The output is presented as the events occur.
Sometimes you want to track the top URLs that are experiencing certain effects. For example: the URLs that experience the most cache misses, or the ones that bypass the cache the most, or even the ones that are invalidated the most.
To view that top list, you can use the varnishtop command.
In order the list the most frequent cache misses per URL, run the following command:
sudo varnishtop -i requrl -q "VCL_call eq 'MISS'"

To list the top cache bypasses:
sudo varnishtop -i requrl -q "VCL_call eq 'PASS'"

To list the top uncacheable objects:
sudo varnishlog -i berequrl -q "TTL[6] eq 'uncacheable'"

To list the top purged objects:
sudo varnishlog -i requrl -q "ReqMethod eq 'PURGE'"


Thanks for the answer Thijs, I will definitely look into what you've mentioned.
But Is it true what cloudways has said that, when a POST call is generated it will clear the cache?

@loginid POST calls don't clear the cache, PURGE calls do. If you want a POST to remove a specific cached resources, you'll have to write VCL to do it. Have a look at https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/ to learn about the built-in VCL behavior.

Thanks for your reply Thijs - we don't want POST calls to clear the cache. It is just that the support people at Cloudways are saying that POST calls will clear cache. I guess they are just making stuff up. I'll try to get back in touch with them.
